# Efficiency issues of assignment statements that may just assign variable to itself

Tags: c#, performance

Question: Is there a significant performance hit when assigning a variable to itself?

Although the code can be easily changed to avoid assigning a variable to itself or to use flags to detect how something should be assigned .. I like the use of a null coalescing operator to make cleaner initialization code. Consider the following code:

```
   public class MyObject
   {
      public string MyString { get; set; }
   }

   public class Worker
   {
      Dictionary<int, string> m_cache = new Dictionary<string, string>();

      public void Assign(ref MyObject obj)
      {
         string tmp = null;
         if (some condition)
         {
            //can't pass in MyObject.MyString to out param, so we need to use tmp
            m_cache.TryGetValue("SomeKey", out tmp); //assumption: key is guaranteed to exist if condition is met
         }    
         else
         {
             obj.MyString = MagicFinder(); //returns the string we are after
         }
         //finally, assign MyString property
         obj.MyString = tmp ?? obj.MyString; 

         //is there a significant performance hit here that is worth changing 
         //it to the following?

         if (!string.IsEmptyOrNull(tmp))
         {
             obj.MyString = tmp;
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: I think this is the question (see source): "is there a significant performance hit here that is worth changing it to the following?"

Comment: My apologies. I should have made the question a clear one liner, Lucero is correct

Comment: Beware that null coalesce is not equal to `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, null coalesce only tests for null and not for empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems to boil down to this section:

```
//finally, assign MyString property
obj.MyString = tmp ?? obj.MyString;
```

To:

```
//is there a significant performance hit here that is worth changing 
//it to the following?
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp))
{
        obj.MyString = tmp;
}
```

Realize, however, that the two versions are not the same.  In the first case (using the null coalescing operation), `obj.MyString` can get assigned to `string.Empty`.  The second case prevents this explicitly, since it's checking against `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, which will precent the assignment in the case of a non-null, empty string.

Since the behavior is different, I would say this is not an optimization, but rather a behavioral change.  Whether this is appropriate depends on the behavior this method is specified to demonstrate.  How should empty strings be handled?  That should be the determining factor here.

That being said, if you were to do an explicit null check, the performance would be near identical - I would suggest going for maintainability and readability here - to me, the first version is simpler, as it's short and clear.

---

Also, looking at your code, I think it would be far simpler to put the assignment into the statement.  This would make the code far more maintainable (and more efficient, to the delight of your boss...):

```
  public void Assign(ref MyObject obj)
  {         
     if (some condition)
     {
        string tmp = null;
        //can't pass in MyObject.MyString to out param, so we need to use tmp
        m_cache.TryGetValue("SomeKey", out tmp); //assumption: key is guaranteed to exist if condition is met
        obj.MyString = tmp;
     }    
     else
     {
         obj.MyString = MagicFinder(); //returns the string we are after
     }
  }
```

Given the assumption in the code (that the key will always exist in cache if your condition is true), you can even simplify this down to:

```
  public void Assign(MyObject obj) // No reason to pass by ref...
  {         
     obj.MyString = someCondition ? m_cache["SomeKey"] : MagicFinder();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't worry about that, the impact should be minimal. However, think about how many people are actually aware of the null coalescing operator. Personally, I find the latter more readable at a glance, you don't have to think about it what it means.

Comment: I always have to worry because my boss is a optimization nazi. =P

Comment: The compiler and JIT is much better at that, but I think I don't need to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

The performance worry of checking if a string is null or empty is of no immediate concern, but you could alter your code to be more concise, I think:

```
string tmp = null;
if (some condition)
{
    m_cache.TryGetValue("SomeKey", out tmp); 
}    
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp))
{
    tmp = MagicFinder();
}    
obj.MyString = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

In other words, I doubt that any theoretical answer will be representative of real world performance, unless you happen to know how it compiles down to bytecode... How about you create a quick and dirty test framework that'll run it 1000 times with random values (null or valid strings) and measure the performance yourself?

EDIT: To add, I'd be rather surprised if the performance was significantly different enough that it would matter in the grand scheme of things. Go for legibility first (although you could argue in favor of both :))

Comment: I have to worry because my boss is an optimization nazi. =P

Comment: Well, as Femaref mentioned below, managed code compilers mostly do better than us humans nowadays, this isn't Assembly or even C code. But if it really matters, make a test loop and trust the data.